# When connecting an Adobe Flex front-end with a Java back-end, the service I created is not shown in the data wizard

Tags: java, apache-flex, blazeds

When trying to connect to the service using a data wizard, no services show on the list.

So I tried to write a bit of code manually to do it for me and show me the default error when no service exists, which is this -

"[MessagingError message='Destination 'LeagueTableService' either does not exist or the destination has no channels defined (and the application does not define any default channels.)']"

So, I believe there's something wrong with the specification of the remoting-config or the remoting destination, but I don't know what. I've followed a few tutorials and step-by-steps but they all seem to do something a little different and none of it works.

If there's a checklist of things I must have done before this works then it'd be greatly appreciated.

Also, does the service have to be of a specific type? As my remoting service returns a List[] at the minute. I'm quite new to this so don't know if this could be the problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: To answer Kevin's questions:

1. I'm using the built-in Flash Builder data wizard.
2. It's an OracleXE database and I'm accessing it using Java.
3. Posted below.
4. I created a RemoteObject and had it return either the default String for a result or a fault. And I got the fault error.

...

As I was going through the config files to post them I noticed one thing that was missing, a small "channel="my-amf" within my service destination tag. And it's fixed!

Thanks for your response, Kevin, it was appreciated nevertheless!

Comment: Before anyone goes making assumptions...

1. Using Flash Builder data service wizard or something else?
2. Java server?
3. Can you post your config files for Blaze?
4. What do you do to get the MessagingError?

Answer (score 0):

If you copy WEB-INF/flex folder of the blazeDS into your WebContent/WEB-INF of your Java back end it should work.